# Scan from last instance of character to end of string using NSScanner

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Given a string such as: "new/path - path/path/03 - filename.ext", how can I use NSScanner (or any other approach) to return the substring from the last "/" to the end of the string, i.e., "03 - filename.ext"?  The code I've been trying to start with is:

```
while ([fileScanner isAtEnd] == NO){
    slashPresent = [fileScanner scanUpToString:@"/" intoString:NULL];
    if (slashPresent == YES) {
        [fileScanner scanString:@"/" intoString:NULL];
        lastPosition = [fileScanner scanLocation];
    }
    NSLog(@"fileScanner position: %d", [fileScanner scanLocation]);
    NSLog(@"lastPosition: %d", lastPosition);       
}
```

...and this results in a seg fault after scanning to the end of the string!  I'm not sure why this isn't working.  Ideas?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note: I have since discovered [NSString lastPathComponent], which works perfectly.  However, my question still stands of how one might do this with NSScanner.

Comment: Can you post the line that is actually causing the segfault. You say it is happening after this loop right.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
NSString *thePath = @"new/path - path/path/03 - filename.ext";
NSString *lastPathComponent = [thePath lastPathComponent]; // "03 - filename.ext"
```

Edit to respond to your followup. You don't need NSScanner:

```
NSString *thePath = @"new/path - path/path/03 - filename.ext";
NSRange theRange = [thePath rangeOfString:@"/" options:NSBackwardsSearch];
NSString *lastPathComponent = nil;
if (theRange.location != NSNotFound)
    lastPathComponent = [thePath substringFromIndex:theRange.location];
```

Comment: And beaten to the answer again. :)